# htmlspecialchars not rendering correctly in browser

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to push all blog posts through `htmlspecialchars` to ensure all characters are displayed correctly.
However once being processed (they are called when pulling data from the database, not when pushing) they aren't displaying as characters!
Just their respetive codes appear.

Here is how I'm fetching the data:

```
<?php
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $results )
    {
        echo "
            <div class=\"post\"><article>
                <a href=\"//blog.jacoblukewood.com/p/" . $result['id'] . "\"><h3 class=\"posttitle\">" . htmlspecialchars($result['title']) . "</h3></a>
                <div class=\"postcontent\">
                <p>";
        if (strlen($result['content']) > 300)
        {
            echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(substr($result['content'],0,300))) . "&hellip; " . "<a href=\"//blog.jacoblukewood.com/p/" . $result['id'] . "\">Continue Reading</a>";
        }
        else
        {
         echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(substr($result['content'],0,300)));
        }
        echo "</p>
            </div>
        </article>

        <div class=\"poststats\">
            <a href=\"//blog.jacoblukewood.com/p/" . $result['id'] . "#disqus_thread\"></a><a>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;By&nbsp;" . $result['poster'] . "&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;On&nbsp;" . htmlspecialchars(substr($result['timestamp'],0,10)) . "&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</a><a href=\"//blog.jacoblukewood.com/t/" . $result['topic'] . "\">" . htmlspecialchars($result['topic']) . "</a><br /></div>
        </div>";
    }
?>
```

And it's displaying like this:

```
Yay it&#39;s working&#33;&#33;

Everything seems good, comments, url&#39;s, random colours etc&#33;
```

My website is [jacoblukewood.com](http://jacoblukewood.com)
Also, should I be using htmlspecialchars before pushing it to the database?

Comment: have you checked the page encoding

Comment: You're simply encoding your data twice it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly I don't think you should worry about htmlspecialchars in the database. If you are using a UTF8 character set you will be fine with the majority of characters.

if you already have encoded characters in the database try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php this will reverse the process for you.

Comment: just be sure to clean your data before inserting it into the database. I personally use this method and have for years

function clean_data($string) {
  $string = trim($string);
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
   $string = stripslashes($string);
  }
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
 }